# How to list fast connect names and not the providers names in OCI using GO SDK?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-go-sdk

I am trying to list fastconnect names that are available for my VCN. The problem with `ListFastConnectProviderServices` is that it lists the names of providers rather than the names of created FastConnects services.

Here is my current code:-

```
func checkFastConnect(compId string) {
    provider := common.DefaultConfigProvider()
    client, err := core.NewVirtualNetworkClientWithConfigurationProvider(provider)
    helpers.FatalIfError(err)
    request := core.ListFastConnectProviderServicesRequest{
        CompartmentId: &compId,
    }
    resp, err := client.ListFastConnectProviderServices(context.Background(), request)
    helpers.FatalIfError(err)
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Can someone please point me to correct API call or some reference where I can get FastConnects services that I created rather than providers name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer to my own query. Actually the correct API is `ListVirtualCircuitsRequest`:-

```
func checkFastConnect(compId string) {
    provider := common.DefaultConfigProvider()
    client, err := core.NewVirtualNetworkClientWithConfigurationProvider(provider)
    helpers.FatalIfError(err)
    request := core.ListVirtualCircuitsRequest{
        CompartmentId: &compId,
    }
    resp, err := client.ListVirtualCircuits(context.Background(), request)
    helpers.FatalIfError(err)
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```